# 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, python-3.x, bcrypt

I'm trying to store salt and hashed password before inserting each document into a collection. But on encoding the salt and password, it shows the following error:

```
 line 26, in before_insert
 document['salt'] = bcrypt.gensalt().encode('utf-8')

AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

This is my code:

```
def before_insert(documents):
    for document in documents:
        document['salt'] = bcrypt.gensalt().encode('utf-8')
        password = document['password'].encode('utf-8')
        document['password'] = bcrypt.hashpw(password, document['salt'])
```

I'm using eve framework in virtualenv with python 3.4

Comment: Did you try *not* `encode`-ing it?

Comment: Yes, if i just use `document['salt'] = bcrypt.gensalt()` it shows "in hashpw
    raise TypeError("Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing")
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing" @jonrsharpe

Comment: It looks like `bcrypt` is returning a `bytes` instance, which *cannot* be encoded. It can be *decoded* if needed. Encoding = `str` to `bytes`, decoding = `bytes` to `str`. – What exactly is complaining with a `TypeError` where exactly?

Comment: It shows `TypeError` at `bcrypt.hashpw` and it says `Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`

Comment: [XYProblem?](http://xyproblem.info) Your issue isn't that you can't encode the result of `bcrypt.gensalt()`. You definitely cannot, it's already a `bytes` object. Your issue is that there's somehow a unicode object in `bcrypt.hashpw`!

Answer (score 5):

You're using :

```
bcrypt.gensalt()
```

This method seems to generate a bytes object. These objects do not have any encode methods as they only work with ASCII compatible data. So you can try without *.encode('utf-8')*

[Bytes description in python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview)

Comment: These objects don't have an `encode` method ... because *encoding* a `bytes` object makes no sense. Raw `bytes` can be *decoded* according to a specific charset to *characters* (`str`), not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

The *salt* from the `.getsalt()` method is a *bytes object*, and all the "salt" parameters in the methods of bcrypt module expect it in this particular form. There is no need to convert it to something else.

In contrast to it, the "password" parameters in methods of bcrypt module are expected it in the form of the *Unicode string* - in Python 3 it is simply a *string*.

So - assuming that your original `document['password']` is a *string*, your code should be

```
def before_insert(documents):
    for document in documents:
        document['salt'] = bcrypt.gensalt()
        password = document['password']
        document['password'] = bcrypt.hashpw(password, document['salt'])
```