# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: flask, pymongo, python-3.6, bcrypt, flask-pymongo

I am trying to build a user login system and I have successfully built the user register page, but when I try to login I get the error below. I am using flask, python3.6 and pymongo. 
This is the error: `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'`
please help.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\elvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in **call**
>       return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
>     File "C:\Users\elvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.handle_exception(e)
>     File "C:\Users\elvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>     File "C:\Users\elvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
>       raise value
>     File "C:\Users\elvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>     File "C:\Users\elvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
>     File "C:\Users\elvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>     File "C:\Users\elvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
>       raise value
>     File "C:\Users\elvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.dispatch_request()
>     File "C:\Users\elvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
>       return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
>     File "C:\Users\elvis\Desktop\flask apps\testmon\even\app\run.py", line 30, in login
>       if bcrypt.hashpw(request.form['pass'].encode('utf-8'), login_user['password']) == login_user['password'].encode('utf-8'):
>   AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

([a screenshot of the error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/493eo.png))

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246412/bytes-object-has-no-attribute-encode) SO question for example.

Comment: Please show us the relevant code (see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , "Questions seeking debugging help" section). Best regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HG-Git: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62317379/hg-git-attributeerror-bytes-object-has-no-attribute-encode)

Answer (score 0):

Only give the `Password=" "`

Example:

```
pdf = pdfplumber.open(f,password='')
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line of the traceback

```
login_user['password']) == login_user['password'].encode('utf-8'): AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Tells you that you are passing an object that is of type `bytes`, not a `str`.
So you are trying to invoke `.encode()` method on `bytes` object.
You need to check what is the `login_user['password']` value, and either cast it to string by invoking `decode()` method on the `bytes` object `login_user['password']).decode().encode('utf-8')` or store a string value in this dictionary at the beginning.

From this traceback I can see, that what you're doing doesn't make much sense, but unless you can share the code, there is not much more I can tell.

EDIT:

```
login if bcrypt.hashpw(request.form['pass'].encode('utf-8'), login_user['password']) == login_user['password'].encode('utf-8'): AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

You can also probably remove the `.endoce('utf-8')` from the `login_user['password']` part, and it could work as well.