# HG-Git: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, homebrew, hg-git

I'm trying to clone a git repository with mercurial and hg-git, but an AttributeError keeps coming up. When I run `hg clone git://github.com/michaelfm1211/simpleserve`, the output I get is this:

```
destination directory: simpleserve
** unknown exception encountered, please report by visiting
** https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BugTracker
** Python 3.8.3 (default, May 31 2020, 07:24:01) [Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 5.4.1)
** Extensions loaded: hggit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/michaelfm1211/brew/bin/hg", line 43, in <module>
    dispatch.run()
  File "/Users/michaelfm1211/brew/Cellar/mercurial/5.4.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 112, in run
    status = dispatch(req)
  File "/Users/michaelfm1211/brew/Cellar/mercurial/5.4.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 298, in dispatch
    ret = _runcatch(req) or 0
  File "/Users/michaelfm1211/brew/Cellar/mercurial/5.4.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 472, in _runcatch
    return _callcatch(ui, _runcatchfunc)
  File "/Users/michaelfm1211/brew/Cellar/mercurial/5.4.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 481, in _callcatch
    return scmutil.callcatch(ui, func)
  File "/Users/michaelfm1211/brew/Cellar/mercurial/5.4.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mercurial/scmutil.py", line 152, in callcatch
    return func()
  File "/Users/michaelfm1211/brew/Cellar/mercurial/5.4.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 462, in _runcatchfunc
    return _dispatch(req)
  File "/Users/michaelfm1211/brew/Cellar/mercurial/5.4.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 1225, in _dispatch
    return runcommand(
  File "/Users/michaelfm1211/brew/Cellar/mercurial/5.4.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 910, in runcommand
    ret = _runcommand(ui, options, cmd, d)
  File "/Users/michaelfm1211/brew/Cellar/mercurial/5.4.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 1237, in _runcommand
    return cmdfunc()
  File "/Users/michaelfm1211/brew/Cellar/mercurial/5.4.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 1223, in <lambda>
    d = lambda: util.checksignature(func)(ui, *args, **strcmdopt)
  File "/Users/michaelfm1211/brew/Cellar/mercurial/5.4.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 1864, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/michaelfm1211/brew/Cellar/mercurial/5.4.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mercurial/commands.py", line 1903, in clone
    r = hg.clone(
  File "/Users/michaelfm1211/brew/Cellar/mercurial/5.4.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mercurial/hg.py", line 900, in clone
    exchange.pull(
  File "/Users/michaelfm1211/brew/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hg_git-0.9.0a1-py3.8.egg/hggit/util.py", line 64, in inner
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/michaelfm1211/brew/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hg_git-0.9.0a1-py3.8.egg/hggit/__init__.py", line 366, in exchangepull
    pullop.cgresult = repo.githandler.fetch(remote.path, heads)
  File "/Users/michaelfm1211/brew/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hg_git-0.9.0a1-py3.8.egg/hggit/git_handler.py", line 283, in fetch
    result = self.fetch_pack(remote, heads)
  File "/Users/michaelfm1211/brew/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hg_git-0.9.0a1-py3.8.egg/hggit/git_handler.py", line 1223, in fetch_pack
    ret = localclient.fetch_pack(path, determine_wants, graphwalker,
  File "/Users/michaelfm1211/brew/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dulwich/client.py", line 876, in fetch_pack
    proto, can_read, stderr = self._connect(b'upload-pack', path)
  File "/Users/michaelfm1211/brew/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dulwich/client.py", line 1015, in _connect
    b'git-' + cmd, path, b'host=' + self._host.encode('ascii'))
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I have no idea why this is happening. I've installed Mercurial with `brew install hg` and hg-git with `~/brew/opt/python@3.8/bin/easy_install-3.8 hg-git`, because I've configured Homebrew to install to ~/brew instead of /usr/local.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
> ```

Check first your python version used for Mercurial.

`~/brew/opt/python@3.8` means probably Python 3.

However: [This `hg-git` thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/hg-git/has$20no$20attribute%7Csort:date/hg-git/xrMW-EK0UiQ/6p8Y5BLEAQAJ) mentions:

> `hg-git` does not work yet on Python3, but support may be coming soon.
>
> `hg-git` can’t run that far on Python 3 and
>   I suspect that you’re actually running Mercurial on Python 2.

See [`hg-git` issue 298](https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/hg-git/issues/298).

Comment: This worked! I reinstalled Mercurial with pip and Python 2. The only thing wrong which happened was that pip installed dulwich 0.20, which doesn't support Python 2(see: https://github.com/dulwich/dulwich/issues/773), but all I had to do was `pip install dulwich==0.19.6`.